# Play! Framework: prevent recompile whenever I try to upload a picture to assets/public

Tags: playframework

I have a PLAY! 2.3.4 (Activator) application in which I upload a Picture and save it to a folder in the /public folder (/public/uploads) of the application file structure. The upload image method is protected as a SecureAction with SecureSocial. Whenvever i upload a picture and it saves in the folder, the following happens:

1. a new compilation of the whole projects starts
2. consequently, the SecureSocial log in session is terminated and interrupts the work flow.

So, the question is how do I prevent the SecureSocial login session from ending or, putting on another perspective, how do I prevent play! from recompiling automatically whenever I add a picture to the project file structure?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As of I know, this problem only happens when U are using `activator run` command (development mode), and [this bug was resolved in version 2.3.4](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/2905).

Check `plugins.sbt` file and sure U are using last version of play framework.
Use `activator start` or `activator stage` instead `activator run`.